# Any query string to rise and fall

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

To handle button events, I generally have to find some child of the parent container. Is there any way to address sibling components using Ext.ComponentQuery.query syntax?

```
var target=this->up('window')->down('combo'); // is there one step addressing method for up and down methods?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [nextSibling](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-nextSibling) method:

`this.nextSibling('combo');`

Comment: Thanks, But it is not what I am looking for. My desired solution is similar to `this.query('[up qeury][down query]')`. By the way which method can be used to search for sibiling regardless of their order?

Comment: There's no method to do that.